# concurrentmessagelistenercontainer spring kafka is not working

Tags: spring, concurrency, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

Topic A create with 12 partitions
And in spring Kafka concurrency set as 4 . And can able to view 4 client I'd assigned to 12 partitions ( 3 each )

Containers as well created for 4 concurrency but while consuming the data from topic in listeners , it consumes sequentially but not in parallel.

Example :
Consumer 1-C completes processing the data then
Consumer 2-C starts then it completes then
Consumer 3-C starts then it completes
Then
Consumer 4-C ....
Consumer 1-C

But rather I want like
Consumer 1-C Consumer 2-C Consumer 3-C Consumer 4-C to consume data in parallel

Comment: Please share you code, it is not clear what you mean by 1-C , 2-C etc. 4 consumers from the same consumer group on 1 topic with 12 partitions , each will get assigned to 3 partition,  that is right, they will work in parallel to process the all topic, if you would look on the total output, it won't be deterministic,  as the output order might change every execution from zero, the only promise is that inside same partition the messages would in the order they are in the partition, how do you check which process is running? Need more information

Comment: Consumer 1-C , consumer 2-c etc... Is thread name I can able to see the multiple threads in java client log but consumption is happening sequentially thread by thread , in parallel

Comment: How much cpu you have?

Comment: 16 cpu , 4 java micro services consuming different topics , 4 topics , each topic have 12 partitions. Each micro services have 4 concurrency . And is num.network.thread broker config plays any role here ?

Comment: Please share you broker config, consumer config, trying to run 4 console consumers getting you "same" kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following github issue and compare to your code

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/247